# Cant connect to server in Hyper-V Manager

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

I'm trying to connect to my server (running Hyper-V Core) with Hyper-V Manager in windows 10 and it will not connect, putting out the error:

> You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer 192.0.2.5.

I used to have a pc running windows server 2012 R2 and it worked fine but its not working now for some reason. The server and my computer are both connected to a workgroup so i dont know if that makes a difference. Also, i can ping the server and remote connect to it. I can also connect it to server manager but it comes up with a manageability error "WinRM Negotiate authentication error".

Comment: As long as the computers belong to Workgroup, there are some permission modifications you will have to go into and a very good guide for doing such is the following from Microsoft's Technet blogs: http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2008/03/28/part-1-hyper-v-remote-management-you-do-not-have-the-requested-permission-to-complete-this-task-contact-the-administrator-of-the-authorization-policy-for-the-computer-computername.aspx